# how to fill Sql Table with Generic Reflection method?

Tags: c#, .net, asp.net, visual-studio-2008, reflection

Hi; I have 4 tables, one of them is main table also there is one to many relation between tables. TID is Foreign key and ID is PK. As a result. i don't want to fill table with classic method. I should access table property and generic <T> I want to set all TID to T_Table    ,C_Table, Q_Table

[image]

MY CODES(this is test project not real project but logis is the same as real project) Below codes return to me ERROR( in first foreach loop): **Null reference exception; Object reference not set to an instance of an object.**

```
    using System.Reflection;

    namespace App.ReflectionToGeneric
    {
        class Program
        {
            static void Main(string[] args)
            {
                string[] PropertyNames = new string[] { "TID", "AnyID" };
                int[] Vals = new int[] { 1, 2 };
                new DataManager().Save<QTable>(PropertyNames, Vals);
            }
        }


        public class DataManager
        {
            IEnumerable<Table> list = new GetData().GetVals();
            public void Save<TModel>( string[] PropertyNames, int[] Vals ) where TModel : class, new()
            {

                var instance = new TModel();
                Type calcType = instance.GetType();
               // object calcInstance = Activator.CreateInstance(calcType);
                foreach (string PropertyName in PropertyNames)
                {
                    // ERROR RETURN TO ME BELOW   !!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!
                    calcType.GetProperty(PropertyName).SetValue(instance, Vals[0], null);
                }
                foreach (string PropertyName in PropertyNames)
                {
                    Console.WriteLine(calcType.GetProperty(PropertyName).GetValue(instance, null).ToString());
                }

            }
       }

        public class GetData
        {
            public IEnumerable<Table> GetVals()
            {
                List<Table> list = new List<Table>();
                list.Add(new Table() { ID = 1, Name = "yusuf" });
                list.Add(new Table() { ID = 2, Name = "berkay" });
                return list;
            }
        }

        public class Table
        {
            internal int ID { get; set; }
            internal string Name { get; set; }
        }

        public class CTable
        {
            internal int ID { get; set; }
            internal int TID { get; set; }
            internal int AnyID { get; set; }
        }

        public class QTable
        {
            internal int ID { get; set; }
            internal int TID { get; set; }
            internal int AnyID { get; set; }
        }

        public class TTable
        {
            internal int ID { get; set; }
            internal int TID { get; set; }
            internal int AnyID { get; set; }
        }
    }
```

Comment: EF will do that for you. You dont need any reflection

Comment: Yes, but please don't do that via delete and re-post; editing in-place is preferred.

Comment: yes i will do thanks your advise...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It looks like the problem is simply that the properties are non-public, so `GetProperty("AnyID")` etc will return `null`. To fetch non-public properties, you need binding flags:

```
calcType.GetProperty(PropertyName, BindingFlags.Instance|BindingFlags.NonPublic)
```

You might also want to loop at something like [dapper](http://code.google.com/p/dapper-dot-net/) which will do the binding for you, and is much faster (it pre-generates IL via the emit API, rather than per-item/per-member reflection).

Comment: i think that. You are great like john Skeet. i guess non-public properies need flags....

Comment: @programmerist no need to guess (about needing flags); I've just stated: they do.